# The AJAX request don't load the js of the response action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a problem with a js response of an action. I'm implementing something like a IM with polling and Redis. The "problem" i found is in the moment to submit the message. I want to do it with a button (normal way) or via ENTER. When the form is submit with the button it works correctly: Create the message and the other user see the message in his screen and the message appears to my screen via create.js, that prepends the last message sent to my screen. When i submit the form with the ENTER key all works well (send message and the other recieve it at the moment) except the create.js, for some reason the create.js it's loaded but don't execute the action of prepend the last message to my screen. I put the code below, thanks you all in advance ;).

create.js

```
$(".conversations").prepend("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'dashboard/kid_conversations/show_message', locals: { message: @message})}");
$("#kid_conversation_message_body").val("");
```

this is the js to permit ENTER submit:

```
  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "#{dashboard_kid_conversation_conversation_polling_url(current_kid, token: (params[:token] rescue nil))}",
    })},2000);

  $('#kid_conversation_message_body').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "#{dashboard_kid_conversation_messages_url}",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize() + "&conversation_token=" + "#{params[:token]}",
        success: $("#kid_conversation_message_body").val(""),
        dataType: "json"
      });
    }
  });
```

The final logs when ENTER key, so create.js is loaded.

```
  Rendered dashboard/kid_conversations/_show_message.html.haml (6.5ms)
  Rendered dashboard/kid_conversation_messages/create.js.haml (11.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 270.8ms)
```

The Create action:

```
  def create
    @message                    = KidConversationMessage.new(params[:kid_conversation_message])
    @message.kid_conversation   = @conversation
    @message.kid                = current_kid

    @message.save
  end
```

The Form, i use Haml

```
.response
  = form_for [:dashboard, @message] , html: {remote: true}do |f|
    = hidden_field_tag :conversation_token, :body , :value=> @conversation.token
    .control-group
      = f.label :body, _('Reply')
      = f.text_area :body, :rows => 4
    = submit_tag _('Send'), :class => 'btn button'
```

Comment: Can you please use the `console.debug(variable-here)` function along the process and share with us the results?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your form submits to `dashboard_messages_url`, while your keypress function ajax posts to `dashboard_kid_conversation_messages_url`. Check your routes to make sure the latter exists.

If that doesn't work you might tell us what you're seeing in the Network tab of your web inpsector.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was the AJAX dataType, deleting it works, thanks all for your help!